# Stored procedure is not running properly When I call from ADO Connection

Tags: stored-procedures, ado.net, connection

I am invoking a stored procedure from VB.Net but it is not running properly. But the same stored procedure is working good if I execute it in SQL server. It is taking about 5 to 10 seconds to complete its execution in SQL server. But in VB.Net, using ADO Connection method (Connection.Execute("Exec Copy_Testset_Folder 7, 31, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0"), it is just executing for 1 or 2 seconds and then it is stopped. No error has been returned.

Actually, I have created this stored procedure to make a copy of existing data. Let say if I have to copy 200 Rows of data from various tables, It is just copying 50 rows and then stopping. It is not thorwing any error message.

I have used recursive call and 3 Cursors in this stored procedure. Please let me know, If any body has solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) object, together with SqlParameters, and the `ExecuteNonQuery` method.

See http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06 for an example.